# error when trasforming tolower, help would be nice

Tags: c++11, stl, iterator

I'm trying to convert a txt file so all words can be lower case. and when I try I get an error I've tried to differ ways but no luck, my code is as followed

```
              ifstream words("sample_doc.txt"); 
              ofstream samp("sample.txt");
              set <string> lower;
              set <string> to_low;

              copy(istream_iterator<string>(words), istream_iterator<string> (), inserter(lower, begin(lower)) );

              transform(begin(lower), end(lower), inserter(to_low, begin(to_low) ), tolower );
```

when I tried to complete I get this error
'int (int)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'const std::basic_string,std::allocator>' to 'int'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that `int tolower(int ch);` takes as argument an `int` or a `char`. However, you are passing it a `std::string`.

```
for(std::string& x: lower)
{
    transform(x.begin(), x.end(), x.begin(), [](unsigned char c) { return std::tolower(c);});
    to_low.insert(x);
}
```

If you change your last line to the above loop, it will convert each string in `std::set<std::string> lower` to a lower case string, character by character, and insert it in `std::set<std::string> to_low`

Hope this helps!